# Ajax method within an added method in jQuery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, methods, validation

I'm kind of stuck with this pretty simple (I'm sure) jQuery/Javascript issue.
Here's the code :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("emailExists", function(value, element, param) {
var email = value || '';
var valid = 0;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: param,
  data: "email=" + email,
  success: function(msg) {
                if (msg != '' && msg)
                {
                    valid = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    valid = 1;
                }
        }
});
return valid;
}, "* Email address already registered, please login.");
```

This function is called where a user type his email address in a registration form, and everything seems to work perfectly, except that my valid variable returned isn't updated, whereas when I use an alert box it is properly done!

It looks like it return the value before the AJAX is done, any idea?

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails, because ajax works asynchronously. your return statement is reached before the success function is called. To make it synchronous add `async: false` to your ajax call like this:

```
$.ajaxA({
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: param,
  data: "email=" + email,
  success: function(msg) {
                if (msg != '' && msg)
                {
                    valid = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    valid = 1;
                }
        }
});
```

Comment: Wokrs perfectly thanks! I know ajax works asynchronously, that's why I could precisely say where the issue was, but I didn't know there was a property to prevent JS, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is the [remote rule option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) that lets you do something like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "check-email.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $("#username").val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but didn't help me with the issue :)